# iOS, Swift - JSON Response. VK SDK

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am using the VK SDK for iOS, and I need to take out the images URLs from JSON response from VK.

The response is look like this: [image: this]

The actual response could be AnyObject OR String, and I only need the largest image URL (photo_1280) as string.

In the response comes 1-10 photos and which parameters I will need to change to get the particular photo like first or second and so on.

I'm using Swift in my project but can understand Objective-C.

Comment: Im not sure I understand your question. In 1 sentence what are you asking?

Comment: How to take out the URLs of images from JSON?

Answer (score 0):

JSON is just a format that lets you exchange information between languages (or objects).

You need to 'parse' the string into a JSON object. Its a little different for each language. For example on iOS I create my UI elements from a JSON file where I load the file and create a dictionary object from it. In your case you are doing it from a string. You need to turn that string into a valid object in your language. In Swift I prefer a Dictionary. So I use a typealias for that and cast the nsDictionary as that type of object.

Then to access objects, I access keys in the dictionary. In your case you would create a dictionary object too, and access the "attachments" object, which in your case is an array so you'll need to do extra processing on it to get each image (i.e. go through the array). This should get you going.

```
typealias Dict = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
    func loadDictionaryFromJSON(jsonString:String) -> Dict
        {
            var JSONData:NSData! = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            var JSONError:NSError?
            let swiftObject:AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &JSONError)!
            if let nsDictionaryObject = swiftObject as? NSDictionary
            {
                if let dictionaryObject = nsDictionaryObject as Dictionary?
                {
                    return dictionaryObject as Dict
                }else
                {
                    println("Error could not make dictionary from NSDictionary in \(self)")
                }
            }else
            {
                "Error could not make NSDictionary in \(self)"
            }

            println("Empty dictionary passed, fix it!")
            return Dict()
        }
```

Now to access things you just do

```
var objects:Dictionary<String,AnyObject> = loadDictionaryFromJSON("{"what":"ever"}")

var whatever = objects["what"]
```

Comment: so i complete the code like [This](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-5zXuxEf8WnamE2QWFxZDNzV0k&authuser=0) but i getting an error on line `let swiftObject:AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &JSONError)!`

Comment: make life easier use swiftyjson